# Relative or absolute path mess

Tags: windows-phone-7, relative-path

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7.1 application.

I have the following folders structure:

```
- Images (**folder**)
   |
   - appbar.questionmark.rest.png

- Views(**folder**)
   |
   - About.xaml

- MainPage.xaml
```

...

I'm trying to create an app bar programmatically with:

```
private void SetUpAppBar()
    {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton helpButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("..//Images//appbar.questionmark.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        helpButton.Text = AppResources.Help;
        helpButton.Click += new EventHandler(helpButton_Click);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(helpButton);

        // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarHelpMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.Help);
        appBarHelpMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(helpButton_Click);
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarHelpMenuItem);
    }
```

But I can't see the icon on app bar. What am I doing wrong?

I have test with this:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton helpButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("..//Images//appbar.questionmark.rest.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

But I get an invalid path exception. I've also changed UriKind to Relative, Absolute and with AbsoluteOrRelative.

**appbar.questionmark.rest.png** is marked as **Resource**, and copy to directory is set to "don't copy".

Comment: You could try this line with a single point at the beginning. ApplicationBarIconButton helpButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("..//Images//appbar.questionmark.rest.png", UriKind.Relative)); And you should take a look at your png-s properties

Comment: Sorry i know my first comment doesn't work just copied it from your code and hit enter to soon, i edited it.

Comment: @BigL Thanks for your answers, but it still doesn't work. I don't see the icon.

Comment: Try to set your png as Content and "copy if newer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pictures Build Action should be Content.

```
ApplicationBarIconButton helpButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/appbar.questionmark.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Try this i hope this will work.:)

This is how [MSDN describes how to add a button to the AppBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431786%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

```
ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
button1.Text = "button 1";
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1);
```

I think your problem is that your picture is set as a Resource and not as Content.

Comment: It works because I set up picture as a Content. Thanks a lot!